# How to retain column names when using cast?

Tags: sql

I don't wanna write duplicate alias for each column.

For now, I have to write an alias for each column that is cast:

```
SELECT CAST([col1] AS DECIMAL(12,0)) AS [col1] FROM mytab
```

Otherwise, the column names will turn empty...

Comment: I don't want to either - but have to - no shortcut to this one

Comment: It is mandatory because as soon as you perform an operation on the column it is no longer "that column" (plus it may take on a different meaning that SQL has no knowledge of).  So unless that cast is redundant (and then don't include the cast at all) there simply is no alternative - you have to give the column a viable column alias.

Answer (score 0):

if you really hate this then a little side-way topic, but you can try a dbt macro like:

```
{% macro cast_name(col) %}

CAST({{col}} AS DECIMAL(12,0)) AS {{col}} 

{% endmacro %}
```

and your original file become:

SELECT {{cast_name('col1')}} FROM mytab